# Unable to publish the page in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, web-part, aspx

I have created a blank `web part page` and a custom web part. I have added that web part into the page. After all the changes when i tried to check in and `publish` the page, the page again goes in edit mode and i am unable to publish the page. I was able to check in the page from the designer but cannot publish the page. I have a `list web part` on that page which is connected to my custom web part.
Does anyone know what is causing this? How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Does your custom web part have input fields such as drop downs, text boxes?

Comment: yeah i have used asp controls for text boxes labels and people editor etc.

Comment: Have you used ASP.NET Validation controls for those fields?

Answer (score 0):

use chrome browser instead of ie it works some times.

Comment: tried but no success